# Flux: InfluxDB conversion of a table from Float to Integer

Tags: influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

Using InfluxQL with this query, one could convert a table from `Float` to `Integer`:

```
SELECT value::integer INTO temp FROM measurement;
DROP MEASUREMENT measurement;
SELECT value::integer INTO measurement FROM temp;
DROP MEASUREMENT temp;
```

How can the same be done using `Flux` in InfluxDB 2?

InfluxDB 2 has an InfluxDB 1 compatibility layer, but this doesn't support `SELECT ... INTO ...` clauses: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/reference/api/influxdb-1x/#influxql-support
So one does have to write the query using `Flux`, the new query language.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `temp` bucket
2. run this query:

```
from(bucket: "<bucket>")
  |> range(start: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "<measurement>")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> toInt()
  |> to(bucket: "temp", org: "<org>")
```

3. drop `<measurement>` in `<bucket>` via commandline:

```
influx delete --bucket <bucket> --start '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z' --stop $(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --predicate '_measurement="<measurement>"' --org <org> --token <token>
```

4. run this query:

```
from(bucket: "temp")
  |> range(start: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "<measurement>")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
  |> to(bucket: "<bucket>", org: "<org>"
```

5. repeat from 2. for all measurements you want to convert
6. drop `temp` bucket